# Is there a way to specify a source IP address for a Oracle JDBC connection string?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ip-address

The server on which the application runs has multiple IP addresses assigned.

I know for mysql, we can use the ?localSocketAddress= parameter to specify source ip.

Is there a way to specify the source IP address to be used when connecting to oracle using JDBC connection string?

Comment: Do you mean the destination address? Source would be where the connection is coming from (i.e. the client). For the server address, just use the IP address instead of the hostname in the connection string.

Comment: most2 needs to specify the source IP, as you suspected. Some clients allow this. Check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634247/figure-out-client-ip-used?noredirect=1#comment1187731_634247

Comment: nope. not the destination address. im looking for a way to specify which ip to use when connecting to oracle db using jdbc connection, given that my box has multiple ip addresses assigned to it.